# Determine whether there are rational numbers $a, b, c$ such that $3=a+b+c=\frac{1}{(a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(b^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(c^2-1)}$

Tags: contest-math, means

I have tried using $AM\ge HM$ inequality for ${(a^2-1)},{(b^2-1)},{(c^2-1)}$ which gives me
$$ \frac{(a^2-1)+(b^2-1)+(c^2-1)}{3} \ge \frac{3}{\frac{1}{(a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(b^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(c^2-1)}}$$
$$ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2-2(a+b+c)+3}{3} \ge \frac{3}{\frac{1}{(a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(b^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(c^2-1)}}$$

Since $  a+b+c=\frac{1}{(a^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(b^2-1)}+\frac{1}{(c^2-1)}=3$,
$$ \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2-6+3}{3} \ge 1$$
$$ {a^2+b^2+c^2} \ge 6$$

However, I can't move on from that.

Comment: I dont think you have done your AM-HM correctly

Comment: I don't think you can prove this using inequalities as there exists non rational solutions.

Comment: You can only use $AM-HM$ inequality for positive reals

Comment: @Asher2211, I think you mean positive *reals*, not just integers. But the "positive" part is dead on.